# Render users' equations in Python

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib, equation

I teach maths and am trying to create a GUI graph-plotting package suitable for schoolchildren. As well as plotting a graph, I would ideally like to render the equation a user enters [eg. `y = (x^2)/3`] in a nicely formatted style - ideally updating in real-time as the user enters their expression.

I have looked into the capabilities of such as [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), but it seems like the user would have to enter the above expression as something like `frac{x^2,3}`, which is not ideal for schoolchildren.

Comment: If you parsed it yourself, you could then render a text string in the format matplotlib requires.

Comment: Sounds like an ambitious first project, but would be very satisfying if you persevere. All the best. Have you decided on other aspects of the project, like a GUI framework (e.g. wxPython, PyQt)?

Comment: Hello - thank you all so much for your help/advice.

Yes - I intend this to be a program for young children/teachers to be able to enter equations and have the program display and plot their equation.

I intend to develop this as a GUI using WxPython if possible.

I have so far found the 'LaTeX printing' feature of SymPy very useful for converting an expression from a string into LaTeX, which can then be converted into an image.

Best wishes,
Geddes

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether you intend to have your students build this plotting tool in python ***or*** you want to build the tool yourself so they can use it to e.g., visualize changes in function behavior as inputs are varied. If the latter, then perhaps it's not important which language the tool is implemented in, so i'll mention one app i think is fits your brief description almost perfectly.

> *As well as plotting a graph, I would ideally like to render the equation a user enters [eg. y = (x^2)/3] in a nicely formatted style - ideally updating in real-time as the user enters their expression.*

A free App called "[Grapher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher)." It comes packaged with the Mac OS X (10.4 and above). The fact that it is Mac-only might be a deal-breaker, still i wanted mention it in case your students are using Macs in a computer lab, as many grade-school students are. (Note: not to be confused with "AP Grapher"--also a Mac app but it's a wireless hotspot finder or something like that).

The basic feature set: fully interactive, enter an equation (intuitive--uses a [subset](http://guides.macrumors.com/Grapher) of the mac key bindings) to create fairly complex equations from calculus, linear algebra, statistics, differential equations, and the like. Once entered, along with a range of values, the equation is beautifully plotted. Grapher has both a 2D and a 3D mode. Here's a [screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Grapher_Screenshot.png) of Grapher's main app window showing an equation plotted in 3D.

Is there a windows version?  I've heard rumors that one exits, but i wasn't able to find any definitive information about it from a few quick Web searches just now.